# How to get the element second index in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array as follows:

```
var arr = [10, 12, 34, 23, 12, 89, 34, 12];
```

In this I've `12` three times. I want to find the second index of `12` in JavaScript. I tried with `lastIndexOf()` but it did not help me. Is there any way to find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more possible solution:

```
Array.prototype.nthIndexOf = function(e, n) {
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in this && e === this[i] && !--n) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
};

[10, 12, 34, 23, 12, 89, 34, 12].nthIndexOf(12, 2);
// >> 4
```

Comment: +1 I think this is cleanest. Only thing I'd add is a `(i in this)` test to the `if` so that it's more spec-like, though it'll rarely make a difference.

Comment: ...oh wait, you're negating `n` ...why? Maybe you meant `!!`? ...oh I see. My mind was in the `for` not the `if`. Nevermind.

Comment: @squint It is not negating, it is `--n === 0`. I used `n` as sort of a counter.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at it incorrectly. The negation is needed to *prevent* breaking the loop. I saw it the other way around somehow.

Comment: @squint Yup. BTW, I agree about `i in this`. Now it should at least look better `:)`

Answer (score 15):

`array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])`

```
arr.indexOf(12, arr.indexOf(12) + 1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Great solution to find 2nd index :)

Comment: Note that array `indexOf` method may not work in old browsers, and you need to use a shim.

Comment: Sad but true. This code won't work in IE<9 http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf

Comment: sorry @VisioN answer is working in all browsers.So i am accepting his answer

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop though the array using a for loop

```
var first = false;
var index = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
{
    if(arr[i] == 12)
    {
         if(first==true)
         {
             index = i;
         }
    first = true;

   }

}
```

Comment: +2? `oO` Has anyone tried that? `i` is not initialized, `index` is defined globally... wow...

Comment: @PSR Could you please spot it?